# While using Stripe API, how to check if page has previous page?

Tags: .net, pagination, stripe-payments

When fetching the list of objects in Stripe you get a response with a "has_more", which defines:

> Whether or not there are more elements available after this set. If
> false, this set comprises the end of the list.

But there is no boolean which tells if there are items before the current set.
How can I get this info?

(So, for example, I know when I need to make "Previous page" button active)

P.S.: I am using Stripe-dotnet library to work with Stripe

Comment: If the first request you make is the first page of a list, the subsequent requests displayed should have a "Previous page" button.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe API has cursor-based pagination.

When you fetch a page using "ending_before", the "has_more" boolean shows if there is a **previous** page.

When you fetch a page using "starting_after", the "has_more" boolean shows if there is a **next** page.

I contacted their support and asked if there is a way to know about next and previous page in one API call, and they responded that this can be done only by doing 2 API calls.

So when I was fetching using "ending_before", I needed to pass the ID of the **last** object in the list as the "starting_after" parameter to make the 2nd API call to know if there is a **next** page

When I was fetching using "starting_after", I needed to pass the ID of the **first** object in the list as the "ending_before" parameter to make the 2nd API call to know if there is a **previous** page

And don't forget to set "limit" to 1 for 2nd API call, so you don't fetch redundant items.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer, it only returns the 'has_more' property for both the previous and next API.

To enable or disable a button need to create two additional variables,

var next;
var previous;

when you click the next button set
next = true;
previous = false;

when you click the previous button set
next = false;
previous = true;

To disable a next button use the following condition on the next button
<button disabled={has_more === false && next === true}> Next

To disable a previous button use the following condition on the previous button
<button disabled={hasMore === false && previous === true}> Previous